# Can't input the user's value to the array, NullPointerException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
public void setAns() {

        if("TF".equals(queType)){
           ans.add("True");
           ans.add("False");
        }
        else if("MC".equals(queType)){
            System.out.println("Enter choice 1 of 4");

            String ch1 = StdIn.readLine();
            ans.add(ch1);
            System.out.println("Enter choice 2 of 4");
            String ch2 = StdIn.readLine();
            ans.add(ch2);
            System.out.println("Enter choice 3 of 4");
            String ch3 = StdIn.readLine();
            ans.add(ch3);
            System.out.println("Enter choice 4 of 4");
            String ch4 = StdIn.readLine();
            ans.add(ch4);

        }
        else if("L5".equals(queType)){
            ans.add("1");
            ans.add("2");
            ans.add("3");
            ans.add("4");
            ans.add("5");
        }
    }
```

ans is an Arraylist . I am trying to add the user's input which is String. When i run it it prints the first message but has an error when i enter the value for "ch1". It basically doesn't read it and it prompts me for a null pointer exception

Comment: Basically, NPE is thrown when you end up with `null.member` or `null[index]`. Since we don't see your full code and there is no full stack trace we can't be sure what is happening, but based on your description it looks like NPE is thrown from `ans.add(ch1)`. Since there is no problem for ArrayList to hold null `ans.add(null)` should work fine which suggests that it is `null.ans(ch1)` which means you didn't initialize `ans` with ArrayList instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly due to `ans` not being initialised before `add` is called. Could you try initialising it before `setAns()` is called or try declaring it as a local variable, e.g.:

```
List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
```